# Display mongodb index contents

Tags: c++, mongodb, indexing

After building an index, I'd like to view the contents of the index. Taking an example for illustration from the MonboDB docs:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
"name" : "Warm Weather",
"author" : "Steve",
"tags" : [ "weather", "hot", "record", "april" ] }
```

Then an index on the tags field would have these values:

```
{ tags: "weather" }
{ tags: "hot" }
{ tags: "record" }
{ tags: "april" }
```

So, I want to run a command, say, `db.weather._tags_.find()` to display said values.

**Question:** Does such a shell command exist? Or is there a way to do this in the C++ driver?

Comment: what do you mean by the content of index ? if u indexed your collection over tags key then, all of the tags in collection are included in your index. am i missing something ?

Comment: @emre nevayeshirazi I suspect it is me who is missing something. This was a simple example but if I try more complex examples, I'd like to view the contents of the index to confirm that my design objective was being met or to check for any anomalies.

Comment: You can also append .explain() to your query to see whether or not the query is using the index.

Comment: @ranman Yes, that I use. I'd like to peek into the index itself to see why, say, a query is not being used. I love getting my hands on the bits and bytes and characters, as it were, to increase my understanding of what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. There is a way, I have forgotten how though, but there are apps for MongoDB that do this so it is possible (I think MongoVUE does this) some one will surely answer who remembers. GetIndexes will display keys but ofc your not looking for that

Comment: @Sammaye I just tried MongoVUE and while it allows me to view documents in a collection, it only allows me to view the properties of an index and not its content. Hopefully someone will come up with a solution via either the shell or C++ code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user1883451

What you have given example is of hash index, mongodb internally stores B-Tree index.

so example you have given is not always correct,  mongodb end-up storing in that way in some case, but  not always.   [It is fine to understand it in oversimplified way]

1. shell is client, and it does not show "internal on how index is stored"
2. driver is mainly interacting with server (oversimplified), it is also not having any idea about how stuff is stored.

A)how to view mongodb index

Best start is to take mongo source code and start playing with it.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/db/  files with index*
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/db/  files with btree*

B)i assume you are trying to do just for learning purpose.  If you are having any specific query, why you want to do that shoot out the query.

PS :
1. there is more code and less doc about internals and source code. 
2. you can join http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-dev

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what's happening when I do ```db.users.find({_id:<keeping this private>}, {_id:1}).count()
2```

Answer (score 0):

> > @ranman Yes, that I use. I'd like to peek into the index itself to see why, say, a query is not being used. I love getting my hands on the bits and bytes and characters, as it were, to increase my understanding of what is happening under the hood. – user1883451 1 hour ago

In that case, you should look at query optimiser and related internals.